# Cucumber-like outlines for RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I'm loving RSpec, but in my quest to make my tests both more thorough and DRY, I'm struggling to find an effective way to test a full table of examples. I've managed so far by writing parameterized functions that I can call from each of my examples, but it feels hack-ish, and still fairly repetitive.

Something like Cucumber's scenario outlines and [this old gem](https://github.com/oggy/rspec_outlines) for RSpec are what I'm looking for:

```
describe "Adding or multiplying two numbers" do
  outline do
    it "should return the sum"
      (a + b).should == sum
    end

    it "should return the product"
      (a * b).should == product
    end
  end

  fields :a, :b, :sum, :product
  values  1,  1,    2,        1
  values -1, -2,   -3,        2
  values -1,  1,    0,       -1
end
```

Unfortunately the gem I linked is 3 years old. Is there something else either as a part of RSpec or another gem that accomplishes this goal?

Comment: last time I checked it was not available in `rspec` and the `rspec-core` team said they were working on it, but that's like 3-4 months ago

Comment: I made `rspec-with_params` gem which allows parameterized / table testing in fairly similar fashion https://github.com/odlp/rspec-with_params - hope it's useful

Answer (score 1):

You could create an array of the table rows and then iterate the rows through the examples:

```
describe "Adding or multiplying two numbers" do
    values = Array.new
    values << {:a => 1, :b => 1, :sum => 2, :product => 1}
    values << {:a => -1, :b => -2, :sum => -3, :product => 2}
    values << {:a => -1, :b => 1, :sum => 0, :product => -1}

    values.each do |value|
        a = value[:a]
        b = value[:b]
        sum = value[:sum]
        product = value[:product]

        it "should return the sum" do
            (a + b).should == sum
        end     

        it "should return the product" do
            (a * b).should == product
        end
    end
end
```